@Transactional cannot be tested with @DataJpaTest
I'm stuck with my unit tests around the @Transactional method. The problem is that I can't test the rollback mechanism inside @DataJpaTest. 
Here is my simplified example application:
@RestController
public class MyController {

    private final MyRepository myRepository;
    private final MyService    myService;

    public MyController(MyRepository myRepository, MyService myService) {
        this.myRepository = myRepository;
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    @Transactional
    public String justForTest() {
        var myEntity = new MyEntity().setStatus("NEW");
        myRepository.save(myEntity);
        try {
            myService.throwsAnRuntimeException();
            // on service succeed
            myEntity.setStatus("SUCCESS");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // on service fail
            myEntity.setStatus("FAIL");
            throw e;
        } finally {
            myRepository.save(myEntity);
        }
        return "this is the end";
    }
}

@Data
@Entity
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String status;
}

@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
}

@Service
public class MyService {
    public void throwsAnRuntimeException() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Rollbacks not working!");
    }
}

So, when I run this code in the usual way (with a local postgresql database), it works as expected: when I call the query on localhost:8080, the response is 500 and the table in my database is completely empty, as expected, because when the @Transactional method terminates with a RuntimeException, it does rollback the whole transaction (even if the final block has repository.save()). 
But when I try to test this code with @DataJpaTest (h2 database in the classpath for the test scope):
@DataJpaTest
class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;

    @Test
    void justForTest() {
        var controller = new MyController(repository, new MyService());
        assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, controller::justForTest);
        var afterTestEntities = repository.findAll();
        System.out.println(afterTestEntities.getFirst());
        assertEquals(0, afterTestEntities.size());
    }
}

I get a test fail and my debug println shows me my entity with fail status MyEntity(id=1, status=FAIL). But I assume that, just like in the real run, I should have an empty repository due to transactional rollback.
So, my main question is how to test the @Transactional mechanism in unit tests?

This happens because @DataJpaTest tests are transactional by default. The transaction is started before each test and rolled back after it completes. Obviously, you cannot test for transaction roll back while inside a transaction. You need to disable transaction propagation using the @Transactional annotation on your test.
@DataJpaTest
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
class MyNonTransactionalTests {

    // ...

}

For more information, see Spring Boot Reference.
Also, if the controller is not a Spring Bean, @Transactional will not work for it. So you will have to add it to @Import and inject it into your test using @Autowired.
@DataJpaTest
@Import({MyController.class})
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyController myController;
 
    // ... 
}


The main issue is that @DataJpaTest doesn't process the @Transactional annotation on your controller method because the controller isn't managed by Spring in your test setup, Try adding a Transaction Test Configuration :
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TransactionalTestConfig {
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
    }
}

then in your test class :

@DataJpaTest
@Import({TransactionalTestConfig.class, MyService.class})
class MyControllerTest {

 @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;
    
    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
    
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

   @Test
    void testTransactionalRollback() {
        // Create a transaction template
        TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
        
        // Execute the test within a transaction
        assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> {
            transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
                var controller = new MyController(repository, myService);
                controller.justForTest();
                return null;
            });
        });

        // Verify the rollback
        var afterTestEntities = repository.findAll();
        assertEquals(0, afterTestEntities.size());
    }

}


in your property :
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction=TRACE

